# Как добавить водяной знать на большое колличество изображений?

Tags: изображения, обработка-изображений, watermark

Есть задание, добавить на все изображения водяной знак. Изображений 500+. Вопрос, как это сделать быстрее всего?

Вотермарка будет одна, в углу. И на каждой фотке в одном, и том же месте

Comment: фронт или бэк, язык какой? своя машина или хостинг? ...

Comment: или может ты ищешь графическую прогу? если так - какая ось

Comment: первые две ссылки из гугла: [раз](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJpPYLxWDts) и [два](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=15402)

Comment: @qwabra спасибо, можешь добавить ссылку на видео как ответ?

Comment: посмотри, попробуй и затем сам добавь ответ ; ) может какими комментариями сопроводишь. например: используйте гимп + N плагин и ссылки на них

Comment: @qwabra ок, спасибо ;)

Comment: Faststone image viewer, irfan viewer и др. Многие смотрелки умеют пакетную обработку с кучей опций.